# How to create a named pipe in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, ffmpeg, named-pipes

Is it possible without much effort (e.g. in command line or powershell), to create a named pipe?

My goal is to write continously to that pipe from a ffmpeg-process.

Without opening a Pipe at first the following command

```
ffmpeg -i "path\to\my\File\name of my File" -f webm \\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg
```

fails to

> **"\\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg: No such file or directory"**

In the big picture, I want to read a Live-Web-Video-Stream to analyze it and take live-actions based on that.
I am working with OpenCV in Java on a Windows machine. At the moment I have different ffmpeg-processes, which record different sectors (i.e. pixels (45, 45, 100, 100) and (200, 200, 100, 100) (x, y, height, width). The results are saved as jpg files in the filesystem and are then opened in a Java Process. This works, but I think I would significantly gain performance by not taking the long way over the files but to directly pipe my input into the Java-Process.

I know there's an option to live-capture videostreams via open-CV but the framework does not support as many formats as ffmpeg does.

Comment: Always check the c# when you cannot get PS solution.  PS is written in c# and you can always use the c# code.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication

Comment: Can you explain the bigger picture? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a much easier way, e. g. let `ffmpeg` write to stdout and capture stdout stream in another application.

Comment: @zett42 I added the big-picture as to why I want to use pipes

Comment: The `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` namespace contains a `NamedPipeConnectionInfo` class you can use.